# How to remove DC power supply noise while load is active?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, filter, noise

I'm using a [breadboard power supply](https://opencircuit.shop/ProductInfo/1000154/Breadboard-Power-Supply.pdf) to power up two STM32F103, two Hall flow sensors, one IC555, and one 16x2 LCD with backlight. While everything is connected I have alot of noise in the system which is interfering with my measurements. Input to the breadboard module is 12V DC /2A.  Here are the osciloscope images of 5v output and 3.3 V output.
[image]
[image]

I was thinking of soldering a 1000 microFarad capacitor before the voltage regulator , and adding in parallel to each output a ceramic 100pF capacitor. Will it work?, And how to actually calculate the exact capacitance required to filter this kind of noise? (Sorry for the badly photographed images)

Schematic of the whole system is located below.
[image]

5V and 3.3 V is connected to the breadboard power supply mentioned above, while 12V is a seperate [module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-12V-To-3-3V-5V-5-5X2-1MM-Buck-Step-down-Power-Supply-Module-For-Arduino/201538070239?epid=25016926490&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item2eec9ae6df:g:tGsAAOSwiIxaLj0m&enc=AQADAAAB8KX%2FKt4E1xf3SDqEdBclaYYoMuE9je4Vj3%2FFGZu1gib1roM%2B7slV6hHapouux0TCXzV8bY0uacU7ystZxwciisUcm%2FTK4irbPmVe6bGWmjSYRFxpmqVRNqMgEyJXhGywdJk5mwVJulwcuSGLrISkzlHeJ8hNURFUgdrCtZX2nJ4Eo3Ndi3prx8pVe9epz01bnHqAUnAyh%2ByXAqwTY5ij6YeKuE0OkWY6ogWJ8QYsi4rnIKoQ7V8zUng8VnSeD1qapmSO%2B3xfYMBPiBqHb1ktAPtL%2FPg%2FvueiDchjcz60WRNq%2BOi%2Fk1OM2TNLxk%2BduU%2BnFST4avuBWcr1gI9YOGWBsVdHrJbNh%2BzLzhpBcFWIQb88JDnlQXV%2Foo6Hkvpoi85tUoRzge%2BN4asm1MzAmT0cp1eYKCczGkS8TMN1uUV1MrIPSszSkBbwbU68K3NTKWIrzmygoi7Jrni9kDTgaP%2F%2BixJChjhTcvaAIv%2BYeBscyTP2tI2vpU8UVr6yKJ0WQzccEikgeoAM3Lo1HbtJNvTdZBhp58EaCOsj%2B1MoxTDtPVtR6O39ycCrbvLUVa1yiRuA%2B7VAq3nvTGz0h1ZZ1XTCN4%2BseOv381FTPmvTmZZOS3cuHtOybTU%2BKPAzyStFN4ReMFKAedUNpDz5a%2FE2%2BkQgCC8%3D&checksum=201538070239830ab075d7294c17afd43bd56a750ae9). [Hall sensors](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-1-2-Water-Flow-Sensor-Control-Effect-Flowmeter-Hall-1-30L-min-For-Arduino/162875521606?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item25ec233a46:g:hbQAAOSwoddabpz2&enc=AQADAAAB4KX%2FKt4E1xf3SDqEdBclaYaxbfdr9wJGbDHK79z%2FUoIHS%2FtSEZP2f4r38%2BiVTrvT98VXqL%2BVhz2%2FdpuX%2FylN3Vd3oeFtj9vrsXtFPArDg270ZXbicCtW2oXbm%2B3uI276%2BkU6fcdECqrfWBoY7OUIEcwlQcMBImGiaUe62D2zcUwsdAKzsLrhqvEW8axCoB7vFoKWRJW4kBfT%2FQyx0RUEuSk2Zk222xVdruri7d1y8OTY6LS2KjKxgYFnG9uGSEuXrB6D%2B0ZOJJl5aB5IN4B0eOeb5%2FH4RtXktJZGlklja07DrH8Y6GxE7Kb9dy%2FtoS2uLrk3WyLALjBASBPcpYOlBOJdrImudlPkQMmcDtIlWhxDDlrrkxe5mSfm7TOm8ODHlmROCQGpxwIw11d9%2BrkQ6PeYuk6YxzejpaVPbesHKM4UiKpVyf20chd5jUA7bk4mD0m6ml6Yz3bW4C4zXjcks6tGoMZyCWHnnA2fvZRmNFQ0BTh%2FVtIz2O2WDJ2E9t%2BhxTz9CbqxJx1PmEZB%2BVQpq%2FZQ7RXFHMy%2FI9u24%2FnnFUX%2BSi8EhmULUnXqeO%2F07L7e%2FRZVhIRn83lBFU5WSI2TUFT1JQz%2FrQfYJR25nvphZJQIrtOwtx14IR7DnXJ%2Fr7U4jQ%3D%3D&checksum=162875521606491c61b84a854537a0abdef9735c3ab8).

[image: Water tanks]
[image: PCB prototype]
[image: Front panel]

Comment: What's your schematic? Have you placed suitable decoupling capacitors for all the devices? Have you placed them in the right place? Have you put in bulk decoupling? If you don't know what decoupling capacitors are, do an internet search "decoupling capacitors". There are many many books written on the subject, so it would be a challenge to put all you need to know in an answer here. if you show your schematic and layout, we can probably advise.

Comment: I agree that we need a schematic. *While everything is connected I have alot of noise in the system which is interfering with my measurements* If I said: "The noise / ripple on the supply is not an issue." How would you prove me wrong? What **hard evidence** do you have. You would not be the first to blame supply ripple, conclude that it is "too much", fix that ripple but still not get a better measurement result! Since you're using a breadboard module, you might have long wires and many contacts involved, that's a no-no for low noise measurements!

Comment: What are the Hall sensors, include a link to their datasheet. All the other ICs generally **don't care much** about supply ripple **unless** you're using the ADC inside the STM32F103 and use the **supply voltage** as a voltage reference for that ADC (not sure that that's even possible though).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The issue is i'm using Input capture to detect the length of the PWM signal (time spent from one rising edge to the next falling edge) to determine the water level in a tank via capacity. Also i'm using IC to count Hall sensor pulses in one second to determine flow. What i've noticed was that when i connect the IC555 timer to  a stable laboratory power supply it generates nice clean signal, while using the module i get a noisy distorted waveform, especialy when the water level changes. So since the only thing i've changed was the power supply it led me to that conclusion.

Comment: @Puffafish I've edited the post with the schematic. I haven't used any bulk decoupling, and i was going to but first i wanted to ask here if that is going to solve the issue since i'm using a protoboard PCB and i have to solder/desolder every change i'm making.

Comment: OK, I see, that is good evidence. You're using the 555 timer for capacitance measurement. Like that it is likely to operate on a high frequency (for a NE555, I would consider to use the TLC555 instead) and can be quite sensitive to supply ripple. You can always just **try** extra supply decoupling and see what you get. There's not much to go wrong unless you connect polarized caps with the wrong polarity. If adding decoupling doesn't work, consider giving the 555 timer **its own** 5 V regulator.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Frequency of the generated signal is actually not high, from 1khz to 10khz depending on the water level. I'll try the extra decoupling , if that doesn't work you are saying i just add a VR before ic555 but from the same PS which is powering everything else? Nice idea , it hadn't crossed my mind . Thank you.

Comment: *1khz to 10khz* OK, then the "test capacitor" has more capacitance then I expected. Then indeed no reason to use TLC555. Yes, the 555 on it's own voltage regulator form the shared 12 V. That way the two separate 5 V supplies (a clean one for the 555, dirty one for the rest) will start up simultaneously and there should be no issues.

Comment: @RobertSabljo - I've just given the last vote to close what was effectively your earlier duplicate of this question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/446798). As we started to discover there, your power connections to the MCUs are wrong on the schematic (but it isn't clear what you have used in real life), and your schematic doesn't match your actual hardware regarding things like BOOT0 jumper and JTAG connections. One point where it *seems* reality matches the schematic is the lack of decoupling capacitors for MCU & 555 :-(

Comment: [continued] So please (a) fix the schematic to match your *actual* hardware (so we don't waste time analysing a schematic that doesn't match reality); (b) please add some photos of your actual prototype board(s); (c) please improve the scope trace images, if you can. However the magnitude of the *apparent* noise will be affected by your probing technique too; (d) regarding the 555, I see you are getting help from *Bimpelrekkie*, so I won't duplicate effort there; (e) it's not only bulk decoupling you need to consider, it's *local* decoupling for the ICs which is apparently missing.

Comment: Have you opto-coupled the motor drive transistor switch in the hope that motor noise would be mitigated? Your motor's 12V supply has a **common ground** with all the other +5v, +3.3v supplies. You are at serious risk of coupling noise everywhere via grounding paths....which cannot be troubleshot from a schematic.

Comment: @glen_geek The schematic is wrong on that matter since i didn't know how to mark seperate grounds in Kicad (i'm a newbie ). 12V ground is complety seperate from the 5 and 3.3 grounds, its sourced from a different power module. I've noticed that if i connect ground from one power module with the ground of the second power module i get rid of all the noise. I don't know why but it does the trick.

Comment: I'm going to chip in saying you really need to put modest ceramic capacitor (100nF is a common choice) right next to the power and GND pins of each component. In terms of your breadboard, put it to the next two holes. Adding another larger bulk capacitor e.g. 100µF for low voltages won't hurt either. You want that 100µF 12V capacitor right next to the motor as well.

Comment: @Barleyman Done that, but shouldn't i take 100µF 25V instead of 100µF 12V because voltage spikes can damage the capacitor?

Comment: Bit too late now but I meant "100µF capacitor for 12V". Yes, 16V minimum, but 35V is a very common value so no reason not to get such. 100µF isn't that big for a bulk capacitor, especially if you have a substantial variable load like a motor.